# Calling macros on creating new word document from template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to call specific macros when creating new file from word template (.dot). I tried events such as "NewDocument", but it doesn't help. Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Where are these macros stored? In the template being used to create the document or somewhere else? Please use the [edit] link below the question to show the code you tried and explain *how* it "doesn't help*.

Comment: @Rich Michaels Templates in the .dot format *can* contain macros and can execute both Document_New and AutoNew macros. Only templates in the .dotx format cannot do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AutoNew

```
sub AutoNew()
    <put your macro calls here>
end sub
```

More information can be obtained here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros

Comment: Yep, it tottaly works as I needed. But, as mentioned in comments, file should have .dotm extension to support macros.

Comment: Auto macros can be stored in the template you are using (although I'm making the assumption that your template is a .dotm file).  The will only fire when you are working on a document based on thhe template which contains the auto macros.